# Continue function after CASE statement

Tags: linux, bash

I have this function

```
function doit {
  echo " Do you want to continue? {y/n} "
  case $opt in
    y) ??????
    n) exit ;;
  esac
  echo " 32b or 64b? {32/64} "
  case $opt in
    32) do32 ;;
    64) do64 ;;
  esac
}
```

How do I make this work ? I need to keep moving forward in the same function after the YES is chosen.

Comment: `true ;;` will do, or its equivalent (conventional to use when it's clear that the exit status isn't actually what's important) `: ;;`.

Comment: BTW, you might want `return` rather than `exit`, if you just want to abort the function, vs exiting the whole shell.

Comment: (And you might think about using modern POSIX function declaration syntax -- `doit() {`, with no `function` preceding -- rather than ancient ksh syntax supported for backwards compatibility; see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete; that way your code will work with baseline-POSIX shells like ash/dash/etc, and will be less confusing to folks from old-ksh who expect the `function` keyword to make variables local by default, which it doesn't in bash)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well thanks, that `return` tip really helped me on another function .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is extremely unclear, but I guess you mean

```
doit () {
   read -p " Do you want to continue? {y/n} " opt
   case $opt in
     y) ;;
     n) return 1 ;;
   esac
   read -p " 32b or 64b? {32/64} " opt
   case $opt in
    32) do32 ;;
    64) do64 ;;
   esac
}
```

The option to do nothing at all in the `y` case seems to be the answer to your question. But notice also the use of `return` rather than `exit` to leave the function, the absence of a `function` keyword in the function declaration (this is only a matter of preference really; but I see no advantage of the Bash-only syntax variant), and the use of `read` to read input (I *guess* that's what you wanted here?). The `return` argument `1` signals failure to the caller, so you can say e.g.

```
doit || echo "$0: doit failed or aborted" >&2
```

Strictly speaking, the first `case` only needs an `n` branch; you'll notice that the code simply falls through if the answer is not either `n` or `y`, and this behavior is actually suitable for the `y` case too. Where this is not the case, a final `*)` case can be used to handle all the otherwise unhandled values.

Comment: Ok everything is working :)
Thank you very much friend !!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use a `case` statement when you only care about one of the branches:

```
function doit {
    read -p " Do you want to continue? {y/n} " ans
    [[ $ans == [nN]* ]] && return 1

    PS3=" 32b or 64b? "
    select size in 32 64; do
        case $size in
            32|64) break ;;
        esac
    done
    do${size}
}
```

Comment: Probably `[[ $ans == [yY]* ]] || return 1` is safer.

Comment: ...though the `case` statement certainly comes out ahead on portability, if one weren't using other extensions.